# npm init install project within /home/myUser folder on ubuntu 14

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04, yeoman

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed nodejs v5.1.0 via nvm, and npm v3.3.12. I also installed yeoman with some generators. However, if I try to init a new project (via npm init or yo some-generator), all the files and "node_modules" folder are installed into /home/myUser, without errors. Even if I start a new project into a different directory. I don't know how do configure this.

Can anyone help with this issue please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issues are permission npm:

1. Install npm with global: `sudo npm install -g npm`
2. Set full permission for npm: `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm`

Comment: Hey man, this solved my issue regarding the npm installation. In my case, I use "nvm", so, I've typed "sudo chown -R $USER ~/.nvm"!!

Now, regarding the yeoman, I've typed "yo doctor" on my terminal and I've got the following message:

"Found a NaN file in your home directory. Delete it otherwise
Yeoman will generate everything in your home rather then your project folder."
I've solved this issue by deleting the files ".yo-rc.json" and ".bowerrc" from my home directory.  Thanks man!!